# Cross validated random forest giving less accuracy reading

Tags: r, random-forest, cross-validation

So i have created a random forest model and another cross-validated random forest model.

The first random forest model achieved the accuracy of:

```
Accuracy: 0.8516
AUC: 0.8891
```

However, when i tried creating the cross-validated random forest model, the accuracy is slightly lower than the original random forest without cross-validation.

```
Accuracy: 0.8432
AUC: 0.8633
```

I would like to know if a cross-validated version is not always guaranteed to be much better than the non-cross validated version, as I'm not able to look up on this reasoning so far.

Comment: Is this a programming question? This looks more suitable for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) as it's a question on statistical methodologies. I'd suggest you review what cross-validation does. Although the accuracy of your model might suffer, that's exactly the point with using cross-validation to get a better assessment without as much overfitting. Higher accuracy alone is not a measure of whether a model is "better."

Comment: Actually, it is the other way around. Cross-validation will almost always report lower accuracy than testing on the full data set However, this lower accuracy is almost always a better estimate of the accuracy that you should expect on new (unseen) data.